# How do I ordinalize numbers from a select list form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

Here is what I have thus far:

```
<%= f.select :year, (1..8).ordinalize %>
```

This code doesn't work by the way.  It worked like a regular select list before I added .ordinalize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
<%= f.select :year, (1..8).map { |year| [ year.ordinalize, year ] } %>
```

Assuming of course that you want numbers as the values and ordinalized numbers as the displayed text.

Comment: Thank you everyone. You're all incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<%= f.select :year, (1..8).collect { |i| i.ordinalize } %>
```

Comment: Even better: `<%= f.select :year, (1..8).map(&:ordinalize) %>`